# Agora ios sdk - random black UI Glitch at left top corner of ui elements

Tags: agora.io, agora-implementation, agora

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7nWC.jpg),(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzNpV.jpg)

- its generated after the agora successfull integration, anybody with the answer please guide me to resolve the issue. thanks in advance.

i tried alot googling and documentation, bt its not working. seems like its causing because of some kind of extension - but its appearing to every type of ui elements like button, uiview etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `chat-uikit`, there's a known problem here:

> chat-uikit is using an UIView extension UIView+YKCorners  to round corners of the UIView which was causing this issue.
> if you don't want to use the extension, you can delete it directly and it will affect other features of chat-uikit.
> We will fixed this issue in our next release.

Hope this helps.